# jq - print values in one line

Tags: json, jq

json input:

```
[
  {
    "name": "cust1",
    "grp": [
      {
        "id": "46",
        "name": "BA2"
      },
      {
        "id": "36",
        "name": "GA1"
      },
      {
        "id": "47",
        "name": "NA1"
      },
      {
        "id": "37",
        "name": "TR3"
      },
      {
        "id": "38",
        "name": "TS1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

expected, on output are two lines:

```
name: cust1
groups: BA2 GA1 NA1 TR3 TS1
```

I was trying to build filter without success..

```
$ jq -r '.[]|"name:", .name, "groups:", (.grp[]|[.name]|@tsv)' test_json
name:
cust1
groups:
BA2
GA1
NA1
TR3
TS1
```

Update: 
the solution provided below works fine, but I did not predict case when no groups exists:

```
[
  {
    "name": "cust1",
    "grp": null
  }
]
```

in such case, the solution provided returns error:

```
$ jq -jr '.[]|"name:", " ",.name, "\n","groups:", (.grp[]|" ",.name),"\n"' test_json2
name: cust1
jq: error (at test_json2:6): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

any workaround appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use the "join", `-j`

```
$ jq -jr '.[]|"name:", " ",.name, "\n","groups:", (.grp[]|" ",.name),"\n"' test_json
name: cust1
groups: BA2 GA1 NA1 TR3 TS1
```

And with a place holder

```
$ jq -jr '.[]|"name:", " ",.name, "\n","groups:", (.grp//[{"name":"-"}]|.[]|" ",.name),"\n"' test_json
name: cust1
groups: -
```

Comment: is it possible to print "-"  in case no group names exists in json? I've tried (.grp[]|" ",.name) // "-","\n" but get error Cannot iterate over null (null)

Comment: I think you don't need the `-r` switch, when already using `-j`. JQ's man: `--join-output / -j:

           Like -r but jq won't print a newline after each output.`

Answer (score 6):

```
$ jq -r '.[] |
      [ "name:", .name ], [ "groups:", .grp[].name ]
      | @tsv' file.json
name:   cust1
groups: BA2     GA1     NA1     TR3     TS1
```

That is, give `@tsv` two arrays, one with the name, and one with the groups.  Each array will become its own row.

In case the `grp` array may be empty and you'd like to insert a `-` instead:

```
$ jq -r '.[] |
      [ "name:", .name ], [ "groups:", (.grp // [])[].name // "-" ]
      | @tsv' file.json
name:   cust1
groups: -
```

The operation `x // y` returns `x` unless `x` evaluates to `null` or `false` in which case it returns `y`.

This will also handle the case where `grp` is completely missing (not just an empty array).